# How to inspect "current" exception in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception, watch

Sometimes Eclipse debugger stops at an exception having current instruction pointer at the end of the method. Debug view says at the moment "thread... (Suspended (exception ...))"

Why it doesn't stop at exception throw place?

How to inspect these exception? To see their messages and stack traces?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the debugger stop where the exception is thrown.

On the *Breakpoints* tab of the *Debug* perspective, click on the "J!" icon at the top. Enter an exception. It will appear in the list of breakpoints.

You can configure whether the debugger stops for uncaught exceptions or caught exceptions or both.

This is particularly useful for NullPointerExceptions.

```
 Why it doesn't stop at exception throw place?
```

If you are stepping over code, you're also stepping over the throwing of exceptions within that code.

```
 How to inspect these exception? To see their messages and stack traces?
```

You can inspect exceptions in the *Variables* view of the *Debug* perspective.

Comment: Four years later, someone has downvoted this answer without comment. As far as I know, it is accurate and addresses the OP's question. Comments are encouraged.

Comment: 6 years later, I upvoted your answer and both of your comments, because it was really helpful and even helped me identify an Exception I didn't even know was occurring! :) HAVE A GOOD DAY.

Comment: I so not see the exception in the variables tab :(

Comment: @CardinalSystem - have you selected a call stack layer where the exception is thrown or caught?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't stop because when an exception is thrown in Java, it will navigate all the way up the stack trace trying to find something that might catch the exception. Eclipse only stops the thread when the JVM reaches the last element in the stack trace, so the exception enters the realm of "unhandled." I haven't found anything specific in Eclipse for how to get the stack trace from it directly at this point. You never have a reference to the exception here. You can use exception breakpoints using the J! icon in the "Breakpoints" view to have it stop when a certain type of exception is thrown, and this will help you get what you want.

Something I would recommend that you do is add a custom [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) that will handle uncaught exceptions like this . For example:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        // Replace the following line with your own handling code
        e.printStackTrace();
        ErrorHelper.showDetailError(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: "You can use exception breakpoints using the J! icon in the "Breakpoints" view to have it stop when a certain type of exception is thrown, and this will help you get what you want." - this is exactly what OP has done, and he is asking how to proceed. this answer does not help with the question.

Comment: @eis - You've misread the question. The OP explicitly asks how to get the debugger to stop where the exception is *thrown*. The debugger is stopping at the end of the *thread*.